# Why cache working set per multiprocessor for texture memory in Nvidia has a variable size?

Tags: texture, memory, gpgpu, opencl, cuda

I saw it here https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability , I don't know if it also happens for AMD.